# OpenGL ES Rendering on Older Device

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm building a drawing application for Android and am targeting Android versions >= 5.0 (`minSdkVersion 21`). I have the drawing working correctly with OpenGL + TextureView on Android 6.0+ devices (tested on Huawei, One Plus, Nexus etc) but on Android 5.1.1 I get the problem seen in the attachments below.

Here's some info:

**Open GL ES Setup**

```
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true);
// Enable transparency.
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 8);
setOpaque(false);

...

mRenderer = new GTRenderer(this);
setRenderer(mRenderer);
setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

I have an extension of `TextureView` which handles continuous/dirty drawing. Also in the `GLTextureView` I have:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getPointerCount() == 1) {
        mRenderer.onTouchEvent(event);
        requestRender();
        return true;
    } else {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
            // Zoom started, so add Undo.
            mRenderer.cancelOrFinishLine(event, false);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any idea why this could be happening?

*This is how it should look (looks like this on Android 6+):*

[image]

*This is how it looks (Android 5.0):*

[image]

Comment: All I can suggest is to take a look at it with the GPU debugger: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-gpu-debugger.html but that appears to have been moved to it own github project: https://github.com/google/gapid Perhaps with that you can find the difference between versions.

Comment: Any errors from `glGetError`?

Comment: I think I found out why, will post as Answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found out why it was happening. Before I had this:

```
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
```

Instead of null I actually created an empty buffer like this:

```
IntBuffer textureContent = IntBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4);
GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureContent);
```

And now I get the white canvas on all devices that I tested on - even on the old tablet that I was seeing the gibberish above too. I guess older devices expect an initialized content buffer.

Comment: How did it work without uploading image data to texture buffer?

Comment: It was working on newer devices, not quite sure but the examples I found all had `null` there.